# How to correctly use jQuery extend

Tags: jquery

Let's have these objects:

```
var a = {
        a: {
        b: [1,2,3],
        c: "a",
        d: "a"
  },
  b: "aaa"
};

var b = {
    a: {
        b: [],
        c: ""
     },
     b: "b"
};
```

I need to merge them in way, where ALL existing elements from var b rewrites corresponding elements from var a. So expected result is:

```
a == {
      a: {
            b: [],
            c: "",
            d: "a"
      },
      b: "b"
};
```

I assumed, $.extend is right function for this. Unfortunately,

```
$.extend(a,b)
```

gives me this result ( a.a.d is missing )

```
a == {
        a: {
            b: [],
            c: ""
        },
        b: "b"
};
```

and using

```
    $.extend(true,a,b)
```

gives me this result ( a.a.b is not changed )

```
a == {
        a: {
            b: [1,2,3],
            c: "",
            d: "a"
        },
        b: "b"
};
```

Is there a way, how to achieve what I am expecting using $.extend or I need to iterate the object manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

> On a deep extend, Object and **Array are extended**, but object
>   wrappers on primitive types such as String, Boolean, and Number are
>   not.

```js
var a = {a:{b:[1,2,3],c:"a",d:"a"},b:"aaa"}
var b = {a:{b:[],c:""},b:"b"}

function deepMerge(a = {}, b = {}) {
  for (let key in a)
    typeof a[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(a[key])
      ? deepMerge(a[key], b[key]) 
      : a[key] = b[key] === undefined 
        ? a[key] 
        : b[key]
  return a
}

deepMerge(a, b)

console.log(a)
```

Comment: User863, thanks, my understanding from your answer is, that "I need to iterate the object manually". Good solution, except 2 issues - you use = for arrays, which means result is still pointing to original array. Slice should be used. And the second - functions should be skipped ( as far as I know, $.extend doesn't copy them ).